# How to convert a captured media file into base64 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, html5-canvas

I am developing an application using phone gap. I capture image/audio/video and store its path in local storage. I need to fetch base64 of captured file and store it in the database and then sync it with server. Is that possible using javascript ?

I tried using FileReader API that phone gap provides but the function reader.onloadend() does not get executed.

Could manage to get base64 of image using a canvas but is it possible to get base64 for audio and video using canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use multipart WS becuase your audio/video base64 very large you

Comment: can you please explain? For the application, initially it will store all data in local storage and once the user syncs the data it will be uploaded on the server. So, I need to store base64 of captured file locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible to get the base64 of a media file
reader.onloadend() is not being called because you might have missed this line reader.readAsDataURL(file).

```
         // here i have a file input and i am using the FileReader Api to read the content on it's change event ( i have no idea what is the event for capturing a media in phonegap
 $("#file").change(function(e){ 
           var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];  

            var FR = new FileReader();

            FR.onload = function (encodedFile) {
                //alert("onload is called.");
            }

            FR.onloadend = function (encodedFile) {
                var src = encodedFile.target.result;
                src = src.split("base64,");

                // This is the base64 encoded string of that media file which you will be interested to store in the database(post to the server
                var contentAsBase64EncodedString = src[1];  
            } 
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }
```

Comment: I have implemented it the same way.But reader.onloadend() does not execute. Below is my code                                         function gotFile(file){
          readDataUrl(file);
         
      }

      function readDataUrl(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.result);
          };
          data=reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          WL.Logger.debug(data);
      }

Comment: @gajjarkruti maybe it crashes, so add reader.onerror = function () {alert("error");} to check for that.